# Is it possible to map a Java object to multiple tables with FK relationship using Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

[image]

I have 3 tables and the relationship between the tables as depicted above.

I am new to Hibernate and I am wondering if its possible to map the above table in to 1 entity? I know about the @SecondaryTable annotation but I am not sure if I can use it here as there is no direct relation between table1 and table3.

If it is possible, is hibernate smart enough to first insert rows in to table1, then use the returned id to insert columns in to table2?

I have searched quite extensively but haven't found a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having an auto increment in DB , You can go for an auto generated id in the Hibernate domain object .

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
protected Long c_id;
```

Then in your flow , Cant you do this ??

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
method m1()
{
entity1 = entityManager.persist(entity1)
entityManager.flush();
// At this stage since entity Manager is flushed you will have the id's
// So manually set the id's to entity2
entity2.setForeignKey(entity1.getId());
entityManager.flush();
.
.
.
}
```